# When I try to check my SUPABASE authentication status, it says undefined

Tags: authentication, supabase

import { supabase } from "..//main";

document.getElementById('login-button').addEventListener('click', async function (event) {
event.preventDefault();

```
const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

try {
    const { user, session, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
        email,
        password,
    });

    if (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        // Display an error message to the user (you can customize this part)
        alert('Invalid email or password');
    } else {
        console.log('Login Successful:', user, session);

        // Add a short delay to allow the authentication state to update
        setTimeout(() => {
            // Redirect to another page or perform other actions after successful login
            window.location.href = 'home.html';

            // Check the user status after the login attempt
            console.log('User after login attempt:', supabase.auth.user);
        }, 500); // You can adjust the delay time as needed
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error('General Error:', error.message);
}
```

});

This my login logic for my CapacitorJS project. The login and signup is working as I can see in my supabase dashboard. But when I try checking in after logging in using this

// Check the user status after the login attempt
console.log('User after login attempt:', supabase.auth.user);

It says undefined and I cannot continue with want I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Supabase auth does not have a `user` property, so `supabase.auth.user` is always undefined.

In order to see if you have a session or not, you can do the following:

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.getSession()

console.log(`session: `, data)
```